# Insert Text After Specific XML Tag in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'd like to create the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<foo>
  <bar/>
  TEXT GOES HERE
</foo>
```

The structure is pretty simple to build with Nokogiri:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.foo { 
    xml.bar {}
  }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

What I can't figure out is how to insert the `TEXT GOES HERE` string inside `<foo>` but *after* `<bar/>`.

Obviously, `xml.foo("TEXT GOES HERE")` produces the text before `<bar>`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-i-text) method:

```
require 'nokogiri'
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.foo { 
    xml.bar
    xml.text "TEXT GOES HERE"
  }
end

puts builder.doc
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <foo><bar/>TEXT GOES HERE</foo>
```